# Set web proxy in Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, proxy

Since the Android port of the Privoxy web filter isn't actively supported, I'm thinking of installing it on a Linux host at home, and configure the web browsers (Dolphin and Chrome) on my Android phone to hit it first for some on-the-fly filtering.

I've moved to Cyanogenmod and was wondering how to configure the phone so that all web browsers go through a remote proxy.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the settings for your WiFi APN in *Settings→WiFi*? In its advanced options, you can specify proxy settings (and more). This is not specific to CM, but should be AOSP (at least with 4.0+).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I was thinking of a setting that would work both for 3G and wifi.

Comment: Proxy settings are always bound to the network used. I don't know of any global setting for that – except when using VPN. Maybe you can specify proxy settings in some browsers (Firefox on desktop supports that, no idea about the mobile version). But then again, it's per browser, and not for all of them in the same place. Maybe apps like [Proxy Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/proxy-settings/com.lechucksoftware.proxy.proxysettings) or [Proxy Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/proxy-manager/com.evanhe.proxymanager) can do what you want?

Comment: PS: [ProxyDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/proxydroid/org.proxydroid) looks promising, too (seems to have a "Global" switch even). Find more with a little [search for "proxy settings"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=proxy%20settings) :)